# search and incremental replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've certain texts. I am trying to replace the numbers inside the [] with number starting from 1 then in incremental fashion. Is this  possible using regex search and replace feature in notepad++.

```
pig[1]
chicken[2]
monkey[3]
duck[7]
goat[4]
buffalo[5]
```

Output >>

```
pig[1]
chicken[2]
monkey[3]
duck[4]
goat[5]
buffalo[6]
```

Comment: Guys please can you give me the reason of negative marking? If no valid reason please remove the negative marking

Comment: @DeanTaylor: That isn't a real duplicate because the digits to be replaced aren't on the same column.

Comment: Don't know about notepad++, but you can solve it easily on the command line, e.g. with this line of powershell: `$counter = 0; get-content .\input.txt | %{ $counter += 1; $_.Split('[')[0] + "[$counter]"; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the job in two steps:

1. First step

   - Move the cursor at the begining of the first line
   - Select, in Edit menu, Edit in column mode (I'm not sure of the label, because I don't have an english version) you may type  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
   - In the pop-up window, choose the initial number and the increment then click <kbd>OK</kbd>
2. Second step:

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
   - Find what: `(\d+)(.+?)\[\d+\]`
   - Replace with: `$2[$1]`
   - then click on <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Regex explanation:**

```
(       : Start group 1
  \d+   : 1 or more digits
)       : End group 1
(       : Start group 2
  .+?   : 1 or more any character except linebreak non greedy
)       : End group 2
\[\d+\] : 1 or more digits enclosed in brackets
```

Replacement part:

```
$2      : Content of group 2 (ie. word before the opening braket: pig, chicken, ...)
[$1]    : Content of group 1 (ie. the number generated in step 1), enclosed in brackets
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Please can you explain the regex you have used, I mean how does it work. `(\d+)(.+?)\[\d+\]` and `$2[$1]`. Thank you !!!